# How to send javascript arrays to java bean

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, javabeans

this is [My Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/XgfuZho0E8Gi5d1CbOrH?p=preview)

In my Plunker there are multiple rows. If they are single iterations then I will take `List<JavaBean>` in java. But Here One row, inside of that row there are many rows, and inside of those rows there will be `n` number of rows.

So How can I take bean in java.

Those all components will save in single table.While retrieving I will bring all the rows at a time.

In that scenario How can I Organize those rows in java.

Comment: use single class which will be responsible for taking whole data from ajax call

Comment: yes single class means One java bean Right?... if that is the case how can I take the list of beans and inside list of beans in that parent bean